# Can I mix ram of same brand but different speed and size?

Tags: memory

Am I able to mix ram from the same brand, but different speed and size? Such as Corsair lpx 2x16 3200 mhz (which I currently have), and Corsair lpx 2x32gb 3000 mhz. According to Wikipedia: “Speed (e.g. PC5300). If speed is not the same, the lower speed of the two modules will be used. Likewise, the higher latency of the two modules will be used.” However I think this refers to 2 sticks altogether, however for me it would be 4 altogether.

Comment: `However I think this refers to 2 sticks` it applies to 2 or more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Capacity

Very often (but not always) RAM slots work pairwise, with a "dual channel" configuration: the two RAM modules are paired in a kind of RAID0 mode in order to get higher throughput. But the requirement is that the two modules have the same size. If they have not, then the motherboard reverts to a standard mode with lower performances.

So you have to identify among your 4 slots which ones are paired, and as far as possible have the same size within each pair. The sizes can differ between the two pairs without any performance hit.

## Speed (frequency)

It all depends on the MB. There is generally a minimum frequency requirement: if you put a lower frequency than required module, the PC won't boot, or will experience crashes while running. If you put higher frequency than required modules, then some MBs will just work at their nominal frequency (not taking advantage of the faster modules) and and some other MBs will adapt to take advantage of the faster modules.

Obviously, for modules working pairwise, the slower one will determine the frequency used by the MB to access them. I'm not sure about what happens between two different pairs, but I would be very surprised if a MB was able to work with one frequency for a pair and a different frequency for the other pair. So I would say that the lowest frequency of the 4 module will be used **for all the modules**.

Comment: My motherboard has 2 dual channel ram, 4 slots total, and it supports speeds up to 5133 mhz. It’s the ASUS TUF z590 plus

Comment: So does this mean I can put the 2 16gb in dual channel (which I already have) and then the 2 32gb in dual channel as well for the other 2 slots and it’ll work fine?

Comment: @Cabbage yes, the modules should have the same size within a pair, but can have different sizes between pairs

Comment: does this also include frequency or is it just size?

Comment: @Cabbage it *depends* completely on the motherboard/memory controller.  The *correct* thing to do would be to have all memory modules be identical.  Mixing memory with different variables may or may not work.  We cannot give a definite answer.  You will just have to test yourself.